# Can't find Magento installation folder in Ubuntu server

Tags: magento-1.9

We bought Ubuntu dedicated Server, I can't figure out where is my magento installed in our Ubuntu server. I am poor in CLI, Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably somewhere under /var/www, you can use this find command to look for Mage.php in all subdirectory's under /var/www

```
find /var/www -type f -name "Mage.php"
```

The apache configuration files will give you information on it's location, (if it runs Apache ofcourse). They can usually be found under /etc/apache2/sites-enabled and have a line something like this:

```
<Directory "/var/www/magento">
```

But, you could practically install magento anywhere you want if you configure it correctly. You can use above find command and and change the directory to for example /home in case it's installed in one of the users home directory.

I'm not sure if it's a smart move to go with a dedicated Ubuntu server if you're not known with it. Who's maintaining it? You should direct these questions to this person as it's server specific.

Comment: You rock, it was there.

Answer (score 0):

In command line, you have to write 'ls' and found where it is. I think it's a better way to ask the directory name  installed to web hosting company.

Otherwise, you can access easily by using FTP in window server. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make a info.php file on root of Magento instal directory and add

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Access the file in browser and you should see the full path in the output.

Comment: This is totally a wrong answer, If user had known the install directory then what was his point of posting this question. Totally irrelevant